# Terminology question on "dereferencing"?

Tags: php, matlab, dereference

In PHP, the following code is valid

```
$a=array(0);$a[0];
```

but that one is invalid:

```
array(0)[0]
```

1. What is the terminology corresponding to that behaviour? (has it anything to do with "dereferencing"?)
2. What is the motivation behind such a behaviour (besides user spite :-P)

I am looking for the **general terminology**, not necessarily the terminology associated with PHP.

(Other example: in MATLAB, the following is valid:

```
s = size(M)
s(0)
```

but that is invalid:

```
size(M)(0)
```

In both PHP and MATLAB, adding parenthesis does not help, i.e., `(array(0))[0]` and `(size(M))(0)` are both invalid)

Comment: Actually, although `size(M)(0)` is not valid in Matlab, it is valid in Octave (GNU alternative for Matlab). Simple Google search implies that 'array dereferencing' is terminology heavily related to `php` and `perl` (and `c/ c++` pointer dereferencing). I have always  associated dereferencing just to pointers. So I don't know how general terminology dereferencing really is among all the languages.

Answer (score 3):

That's called **Array dereferencing**, and will become available in **PHP 5.4** *(which is currently in alpha)*

Note *(thanks Gordon)* : what you are asking for, with `array()`<sup>1</sup>, is not possible even in PHP 5.4 -- but **it'll work for functions**.

A couple of sources :

- [RFC - Function Array Dereferencing](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/functionarraydereferencing)
- [Features in PHP trunk: Array dereferencing](http://schlueters.de/blog/archives/138-Features-in-PHP-trunk-Array-dereferencing.html), when it was unsure whether there would be a PHP 5.4 or a PHP 6
- And, last but not least, the *(currently last)* news on [**php.net**](http://php.net/) : [PHP 5.4 alpha1 released](http://www.php.net/archive/2011.php#id2011-06-28-1)

Quoting that last news :

> Here is an incomplete list of changes: 
>  - Added: Traits language
>   construct 
>  **- Added: Array dereferencing support** 
>  - Added:
>   DTrace support 
>  - Improved: Improved Zend Engine memory usage and
>   performance 
>  - Moved: ext/sqlite moved to pecl (sqlite3 support is
>   still built-in)

<sup>1.</sup><sub>[`array()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) is not a function, even if it looks like one -- it's actually what PHP calls a language construct ; and those don't behave like functions.</sub>

Comment: @Gordon : true, I've edited my answer to point out that this will work for **functions** -- might re-edit to insist on the fact that `array()` is not a function, though ; thanks for your comment :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is called "array dereferencing" and it will be available for use in PHP5.4.

Comment: I'm looking for the general idea. Is it the same terminology for the MATLAB behaviour? And why was it not available in php 1.0 in the first place? That seems so natural...

Comment: @Olivier PHP was missing a lot of obvious features over the years. It's gradually shifted from a very web-oriented language to a full-featured, general purpose language.

Comment: @Oliver: Why was it not available in PHP 1.0? Because the general idea was to return what was wanted (i.e. not an array if only a single value is desired). Why is it available now? Sometimes we give in to peer pressure and add things that "the masses" request.