# Is it possible to reference a specific element of an anonymous array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, indexing, anonymous

This is probably a simple question, and I'm afraid the answer might be "no", but...

Here's a simple piece of code:

```
function func1() {
  $bt = debug_backtrace();
  print "Previous function was " . $bt[1]['function'] . "\n";
}
```

Now...  Can this be done without the temporary variable?  In another language, I might expect to be able to say:

```
function func1() {
  print "Previous function was " . (debug_backtrace())[1]['function'] . "\n";
}
```

Alas, in PHP, this results in an error:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[' ...
```

If it can't be done, it can't be done, and I'll use a temporary variable, but I'd rather not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, direct dereferencing is unfortunately not supported in current versions of PHP, but will apparently come in PHP 5.4.

Also see [Terminology question on "dereferencing"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6800464/terminology-question-on-dereferencing).

Answer (score 1):

Array dereferencing is not available in PHP 5.3 right now, but it will be available in PHP 5.4 ([PHP 5.4.0 RC2 is currently available for you to tinker with](http://qa.php.net/)). In the meantime, you can use `end()`, `reset()`, or a helper function to get what you want.

```
$a = array('a','b','c');
echo reset($a);          // echoes 'a'
echo end($a);            // echoes 'c'
echo dereference($a, 1); // echoes 'b'

function dereference($arr, $key) {
    if(array_key_exists($key, $arr)) {
        return $array[$key];
    } else {
        trigger_error('Undefined index: '.$key); // This would be the standard
        return null;
    }
}
```

Note that `end()` and `current()` will reset the array's internal pointer, so be careful.

For your convenience, if you'll be chaining your dereferences this might come in handy:

```
function chained_dereference($arr, $keys) {
    foreach($keys as $key) {
        $arr = dereference($arr, $key);
    }

    return $arr;
}

// chained_dereference(debug_backtrace(), array(1, 'function')) = debug_backtrace()[1]['function']
```